# How do I get "walkscore" for some addresses (API) through Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to get "walkscore" (through walkscore.com) for some addresses in the US. I used the following python script but I keep getting errors (Failed to fetch Walk Score...)

`import requests

```
# Define your Walk Score API key
API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXX'

# Define the address for which you want to get the Walk Score
address = "450 Wilson Avenue, Morgantown, WV, 26505"

# Define the base URL for the Walk Score API
base_url = 'http://api.walkscore.com/score'

# Prepare parameters for the API request
params = {
'format': 'json',
'address': address,
'lat': '',
'lon': '',
'transit': '1',
'bike': '1',
'wsapikey': API_KEY
}

# Make the API request
response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
# Extract the Walk Score from the response
data = response.json()
walk_score = data['walkscore']
print(f"Walk Score for {address}: {walk_score}")
else:
print(f"Failed to fetch Walk Score for address: {address}")`
```

I tried the Python script above but the script does give me any results. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but any help is appreciated

Comment: What *is* the response code?  Also, the code posted is indented improperly.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://www.walkscore.com/professional/api.php), `lat` and `lon` are required parameters.  You've only provided empty strings.

Comment: Thanks (sorry, it is my first post) I wanted to do this in a batch and failed (I have 1500 Lat/Long)

Comment: And what was the response code returned? I expect the lat/lon should be a valid location near the address.